# Best way to switch UIViewControllers based on different input in an ios application

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, xcode-storyboard

What I am trying to do simply change views based on some data. To demonstrate exactly what I am trying to do I have constructed a little example to demonstrate. I used a UISegmentedControl to simulate data data then when a button is pressed, it would switch between views based on the value of the UISegmentedControl. Here is the storyboard...

[image]

You can see that there is a base view with a UISegmentedControl, then there is a button on that same view that will trigger a switch of view controllers based on the state of the UISegmentedControl to one of the three view controllers on the right. I have included the class of my base UIViewController so that you all can see how I achieve the switching of views.

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    var nextViewIdentifier: String? = nil

    @IBAction func switchViewButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        if (nextViewIdentifier != nil) {
            let nextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(nextViewIdentifier!) as! UIViewController
            self.showViewController(nextView, sender: self)
        }
    }


    @IBAction func valueChanged(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            nextViewIdentifier = "View1"
        case 1:
            nextViewIdentifier = "View2"
        case 2:
            nextViewIdentifier = "View3"
        default:
            nextViewIdentifier = nil
        }
    }  
}
```

So, the first function `switchViewButtonPressed` is called when the button is pressed and it will switch the view based on the variable `nextViewIdentifier`. The second function `valueChanged` simply changes the `nextViewIdentifier` variable when a button on UISegmentedControl is pushed.

---

All of this code works, but it doesn't seem like a natural way to implement this in a storyboard format. It would seem like there should be something else to achieve the effect that I am looking for. I am asking if anyone has a better way to change views based on data that is not previously known in advance and when these views are completely different. Another way that I assume that I could do this is by just stacking different views in one view controller and then picking the one that I want through a `prepareForSegue` method. Anyway, any suggestions about what is the best way to switch view controllers in this context is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone cares, the way that I solved this problems was by creating segues from main view controller itself and naming the segues with an identifier. Then, based on the position of the UISegmentedControl I called the segue with the identifier with the method `self.performSegueWithIdentifier(<String Identifier>, sender: self)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a container view with "embed" segues. Execute the segues when you press the buttons on your segmented control. More info on container views:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13buSJ9XeQI

Answer (score 0):

You should try to build an app based on a UITabBar, it's designed for switching between views. There's more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** If Views 1/2/3 are *unrelated* sections of your app, a `UITabBarController` makes sense. For example, the "App Store" and "iTunes Store" apps use tab bars.

**Option 2:** If Views 1/2/3 show subsets of *similar* info, you could use a single `UITableViewController` and just reload the tableView with different data when a different segment is selected. For example, the "App Store" app has a Top Charts tab which has a `UISegmentedControl` for displaying Paid, Free, and Top Grossing apps. No need to use 3 different view controllers for this.

**Option 3:** If Views 1/2/3 show *related* info but in *different ways*, you could use a parent `UIViewController` with a `UIContainerView` to embed `UIViewController`s 1/2/3. For example, the "iTunes Store" app has a Movies tab which has a `UISegmentedControl` for displaying Featured and Charts. Charts looks like a typical table view, while Featured looks more sophisticated.

I just recently implemented option 3 in my own app using this excellent sample code from another developer: https://github.com/mluton/EmbeddedSwapping. I was surprised how easy it is and how well it works.